# Make sure the php script can be only excecuted from command line (or as a cron job)

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

This is the code I'm using, is it enough to make sure the script can be only run as a cron job? It sure does work but maybe there is something I have missed.

```
   if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli') {
     die("You are not allwod here");
    }
```

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php#89858 :  Very important note related to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that will work. I would also make sure the script is outside the root directory.

Comment: Right, in a deployment to an unknown environment. That would have required details that the OP did not post. If that is the case you are correct... if not, the answer is still valid as it would be outside the root, and he would only be looking for 'cli' not cgi-fcgi. I'm not sure I get your point.

Comment: What does "to an unknown environment" mean?